# Создание при помощи gulp.dest() каталога 'build'

Tags: node.js, gulp

Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении смотреть.
Мне нужно создать в каждом родительском каталоге каталог 'build' и после в него положить скомпилированный файл.

До сборки:

```
Project
    |-- template
        |-- base
        |   |-- base.jade
        |
        |-- landing
            |-- landing.jade
```

После сборки:

```
Project
    |-- template
        |-- base
        |   |--build
        |   |   |-- base.html
        |   |   
        |   |-- base.jade
        |
        |-- landing
            |--build
            |   |-- landing.html
            |
            |-- landing.jade
```

Перепробовал разные варианты. Начал с: этот код положит собранные файлы рядом с исходником:

```
gulp.task('html:dev', ['del:html'], function() {
    return gulp.src('templates/**/[^_]*.jade', { base: './' } )
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlhint())
        .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            return file.base
        }))
});
```

Этот код создаст отдельно каталог 'build', а в нем каталог 'base', 'landing' и в каждый из них скомпилированный свой файл:

```
gulp.task('html:dev', ['del:html'], function() {
    return gulp.src('templates/**/[^_]*.jade', { base: './' } )
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlhint())
        .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('templates/build');



Project
    |-- template
        |--build
        |   |-- base
        |   |   |-- base.html
        |   |
        |   |-- landing
        |       |-- landing.html
        |
        |--base
        |   |--base.jade
        |
        |--landing
            |--landing.jade
```

Иначе говоря, `gulp` работает с потоком файлов и весь поток "ложит" в `template/build`. Если укажу любой другой путь, он создаст католог, а в нем подкаталоги и скомпилированные файлы.

Буду благодарен даже за подсказки, не готовые решения. Спасибо

---

Нашел решение данного вопроса. Для этого использовал модуль gulp-rename. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename/
В начале его подключим:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

За тем, после записи `.pipe(htmlhint.reporter())` нужно вставить некий код, в результате чего код примет следующий вид:

```
gulp.task('html:dev', ['del:html'], function() {
    return gulp.src('templates/**/[^_]*.jade' )
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlhint())
        .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/build";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('templates/build');
});
```

Надуюсь будет полезным. Спасибо всем за внимание и желаю быстрого поиска и легких решений :)

Answer (score 1):

Выделил ответ из вопроса:

Нужно использовать модуль gulp-rename. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename/ В начале его подключим:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

За тем, после записи .pipe(htmlhint.reporter()) нужно вставить некий код, в результате чего код примет следующий вид:

```
gulp.task('html:dev', ['del:html'], function() {
    return gulp.src('templates/**/[^_]*.jade' )
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(htmlhint())
        .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/build";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('templates/build');
});
```